# How to use arrange within a for?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Starting from a data.frame, I want to create several others with different orderings. I'll put an example straight away because I believe it's easier to understand my doubts.

```
data = data.frame(x1 = sample(1:100,20),
                  x2 = sample(1:100,20),
                  x3 = sample(1:100,20),
                  x4 = sample(1:100,20),
                  x5 = sample(1:100,20))
all_data <- list()
library(dplyr)
for (i in 1:5) {
  all_data[[i]] <- arrange(data, colnames(data)[1:i])
}
```

So based on the example above, I would like to create several data.frames, where each one will be ordered based on a set of columns. Starting from the first data.frame which will be ordered only by the first column. Then the second data.frame that will be sorted based on the first and second column. Then the third, which will be in relation to the first, second and third column, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:5) {
     all_data[[i]] <- data %>% arrange(across(1:i))
 }
```

Comment: This approach won't work because it yields the same `data.frame` for each element in the list since it begins sorting with column 1 - to test this, run `all.equal(all_data[[1]], all_data[[3]])` (or any `all_data[[i]]`) and it will return `TRUE`

Comment: I think you may be getting that result because the example df likely doesn’t have the same values across rows? Thus, it’s not doing much sorting across multiple columns. Maybe test with like

Comment: Ah yes I was wrong -  indeed since the default in `sample` is `replace = FALSE` all the values in `x1 = sample(1:100, 20)` were unique so there was no subsequent sorting

Comment: Nice, we can even get rid of the `for` loop: `tibble(id = 1:5) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(data = list(arrange(data, across(c(1:id)))))`